# ASP.NET error handling for 404 pages without extension

Tags: asp.net, https, iis-7

I have a website:[Website Link](https://friliv.dk/) with a problem, when it comes to extension less calls.
if you try something like:
[This](https://www.friliv.dk/nothing-here)

I would like the user to go to:

[here](https://www.friliv.dk/findes-ikke?code=404)

but that is not what happens.

How can i change that?

Atm. i have this in my `web.config`:

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
       <error statusCode="400" redirect="/Error.aspx?code=400" />
       <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error.aspx?code=403" />
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error.aspx?code=404" />
       <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error.aspx?code=500" />
    </customErrors>
```

and

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Some rewriting sends `Error.aspx` to "/findes-ikke"

After som more testing, with no luck, this is my entire web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>   
    <compilation batch="false" targetFramework="4.7.1" debug="true" />
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error.aspx?code=404" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/findes-ikke?code=404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

change the web.config line to:

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="/findes-ikke?code=404" />
```

You can also try to add following in web.config to redirect all http requests:

```
 <system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
     <remove statusCode="404"/>
     <error statusCode="404" path="/findes-ikke?code=404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  </httpErrors>
```

You can also do this to redirect all error requests.  Make this change in the code you have given above:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/findes-ikke?code=404" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
```

Comment: No, does nothing, and I can't see why it would. 

All my rewriting does is sending calls to /findes-ikke to /Error.aspx

Comment: @AxelAndersen I have added some more things in my comment. Have a look.

Comment: @AxelAndersen You should have a page located at  /findes-ikke URL.

Comment: I do have one: https://www.friliv.dk/findes-ikke?code=404 but the last suggestion gives me the same result

Comment: @AxelAndersen Try this, it should work:    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/findes-ikke?code=404" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">

Comment: No, no change. I would be just as happy if it would go to /Error.aspx.

Comment: @AxelAndersen When you added my code of customErrors then did you remove  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /> which was there ealrier ?

Comment: I have now edited my original question, and posted my entire web.config. I have also tried replacing /Error.aspx with /findes-ikke